# Python - How do I authenticate SSH connection with Fabric module?

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, paramiko, fabric

I'm trying to SSH into a Raspberry Pi on a subnet via ethernet using the Fabric module but I can't figure out how to authenticate the connection.

My code so far is as follows

```
import fabric  

c = fabric.Connection(host = "192.168.3.151", port = 22, user = "pi")  
c.run("touch Desktop/new_file.txt")
```

Obviously I haven't put in my password, "Raspberry", anywhere in the above code to authenticate the SSH connection. I've been trying to understand the Fabric documentation but it's a little beyond me so I'm hoping someone can tell me how to input the password to authenticate the connection (and also authenticate any commands using `sudo`).

Thanks!

Comment: There is a `--prompt-for-passphrase` option, but it doesn't appear to work for me. I'm just getting an AuthenticationException when I run your code. You could try using key authentication instead

Comment: @Peter Gibson is there not a way to input the password in plain text within the python script so that it autofills the password prompt without using key authentication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you can pass options to the `Connection` constructor that will be passed on to `SSHClient.connect`

```
c = fabric.Connection("192.168.3.151", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs={'password': 'raspberry'})
```

Note it's generally a bad idea to store your passwords in plain text, especially in code.

See http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.1/concepts/authentication.html as well as http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.1/concepts/configuration.html

Comment: Brilliant - I've been trying to figure that out all day thank you! I'll take a look to try to understands how to log in more securely but this is a start. I'm just a beginner so this module may be a bit out of my depth to be honest.